# Serial device driver implementation

Tags: c#, serial-port

Here I'm trying to develop a good pattern for executing commands and receiving responses over COM port. What would you say about this one, are there obvious flaws in it?

```
public int COMTimeout { get; set; } = 5000; //ms
private SerialPort _serial;
public bool getLinkState()
    {
        if (_serial != null && _serial.IsOpen)
        {
            try
            {
                _serial.WriteLine("state");
                int time = 0;
                bool state = false;
                do
                {
                    Thread.Sleep(10);
                    time += 10;
                    if (_serial.BytesToRead > 0)
                    {
                        _readbuffer = _readbuffer + _serial.ReadLine();
                        int pos = _readbuffer.IndexOf("OK\r");
                        if (pos > -1 )
                        {
                            state = true;
                            _readbuffer = _readbuffer.Remove(pos, 3);
                        }
                    }
                } while (!state && time < COMTimeout);
                if (state)
                    return true;
                else
                {
                    OnCommandTimeout?.Invoke(this, new DEventArgs("state"));
                    return false;
                }
            }
            catch (TimeoutException) { OnCommandTimeout?.Invoke(this, new DEventArgs("state")); }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Also, what would you say about implementing a separate event for every command, that fires on successful execution?

Comment: While code review is to be promoted, this is not really the right forum for it. That being noted, at first sight I have two remarks:
- Thread.Sleep(...) stalls the whole thread. Make your method async and use 'await Thread.Delay(...)' instead.
- using Thread.Sleep(..) to base your timing on is awfull and certainly not accurate. You could use Datetime.Now to get the exact time when starting. In the loop you calculate the difference between actual time and the starttime to decide when to timeout.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because reviewing working code belongs to codereview.